Azure DevOps Pipeline Deploy to multiple App Services
I am working with Azure DevOps pipelines, and I need to deploy to multiple Azure App Services that are in different resource groups. I don't want to manually add each Azure App Service, as I might have, for example, 100 of them. How can I deploy to all App Services in an automated way? Additionally, when I create a new resource group and Azure App Service, I want the deployment to be done automatically to that App Service.
I need a solution where, upon adding a new resource group and app service in the Azure portal, it is automatically added to the Azure pipeline and deployed.

I need a solution where, upon adding a new resource group and app service in the Azure portal, it is automatically added to the Azure pipeline and deployed - you'd have to create a script or other kind of automation to do that for you. But honestly I wouldn't go that way. If you organise properly the pipeline(s) and related templates you don't have to waste more than a few minutes to add some variables or parameters for the new App Service. Just because you can automate something doesn't mean you have to - keep it simple.

Based on the requirement to use a pipeline to create and deploy to multiple new Azure web apps in new resource groups, here is the sample workflow with the YAML pipeline for your reference.
In the CD stage, it will expand multiple concurrent deployment jobs for each element in ${{ parameters.AzureWebApps }}, iterate the app info into the AzureCLI task to create new resource groups and web apps and then deploy the artifact generated during CI stage into each of the new apps.
name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
- master

parameters:
- name: AzureWebApps
  type: object
  default:
  - appName: azwebapp-win-xxxxxx1
    rgName: rg-azwebapp1
    location: southeastAsia
  - appName: azwebapp-win-xxxxxx2
    rgName: rg-azwebapp2
    location: westus

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build App
    variables:
      BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
      BuildConfiguration: 'release'
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Instal .NET 8
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '8.x'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: dotnet restore
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        verbosityRestore: 'Detailed'
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: Build solution **\*.sln
      inputs:
        solution: '**\*.sln'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAppContent\\"'
        platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: Archive Files
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAppContent'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: CD
  jobs:
  - ${{ each app in parameters.AzureWebApps }}:
    - deployment: Deploy_${{ replace(app.appName, '-', '_') }}
      displayName: Create and deploy to ${{ app.appName }}
      environment: E-AzureWebAppDotNetCore
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: AzureCLI@2
              displayName: Use Azure CLI to create new app
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSubX'
                scriptType: 'ps'
                scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                inlineScript: |
                  Write-Host "================ 1. Create New Resource Group ${{ app.rgName }} ================"
                  az group create --name ${{ app.rgName }} --location ${{ app.location }}
                  Write-Host "================ 2. Create New App Service Plan ================"
                  az appservice plan create --name asp-${{ app.appName }} --resource-group ${{ app.rgName }} --sku FREE
                  Write-Host "================ 3. Create New Azure Web App ${{ app.rgName }} ================"
                  az webapp create --name ${{ app.appName }} --resource-group ${{ app.rgName }} --plan asp-${{ app.appName }} --runtime `"DOTNET`|8`"
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'ARMSvcCnnWIFSubX'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: '${{ app.appName }}'
                packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'


Still, there are many other ways you can try to create new resource groups and web apps via different pipeline tasks; this is only a demo for you to understand the workflow that a pipeline can complete.

I think we misunderstood each other. What I wanted was that in case I have, for example, 100 Azure App Services, and each service is in a different resource group. How can I deploy a project from azure repos and have it reflected on all created app services?
I need this because in Blazor, I have automated the creation of a resource group, hosting plan, app service, Azure Key Vault, SQL server, and database using Azure SDK .NET. Now, when I create a new resource (Azure App Service), I need it to automatically be added to the deployment pipeline.

You haven't share in your original post how you automated the creation of the resources. As far as I understand the requirement, please be noted there is no functionality out-of-the-box to trigger a pipeline whenever you have just created a new web app in a new resource group. Since Azure Pipelines are also a kind of automation tool, you may consider using azure pipelines to create the resources and deploy.

If possible, you can add the functionality in your current automation workflow to send API requests to run pipeline with the app info in the payload of templateParameters to replace the parameter default values.

Sure and Glad to help. I don't know what your current automation workflow is like and I am not sure what deployment tool you prefer. As you are reaching out to Azure DevOps subcommunity, it appears to me that to trigger a pipeline is also a way to add the deployment workflow, right? All the deployment works can be defined in a YAML pipeline orchestration.
